# php export to xls without library

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

I would like to export data from sql to xls (better would be xlsx) without a third party library.

This is my code:

```
// DB Connection included by a config.php file

$sql = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM myTable" );
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export.csv');
ExportFile($result);
    
function ExportFile($records) {
    
    $heading = false;
  
    foreach($records as $row) {
      
      if(!$heading) {
          echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
          $heading = true;
      }
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
    }
     
}
exit;
```

This works.
But if I change the header to Export.xls it works but with an "error message" of excel.

```
The file format and the file extension of 'Export.xls' do not match. The file may be corrupted or unsafe. You should not open it if you do not trust its source. Do you still want to open the file?
```

and if I changed it to Export.xlsx:

```
The file 'Export.xlsx' cannot be opened by Excel because the file format or extension is invalid. Check if the file is corrupted and if the file extension matches the file format.
```

How can I solve it, to realize it with xls without error message (better with xlsx)?

Comment: CSV is a text file, xlsx is a zip constructed of all sort of xmll files and such. Not do-able I think.

Comment: You're exporting a CSV/TSV file. That's something completely different from an `.xlsx` file. You could reinvent the wheel or simply use a 3rd party library

Comment: Basic XLSX is pretty simple untill you need extended features. Create almost-empty xlsx file, unzip and look what's inside. Format specs are open AFAIK.